# ActionBar-PullToRefresh progressbar is static with jfeinstein10 SlidingMenu

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to use Chris Banes' ActionBar-PullToRefresh with this sliding menu library but I've got a problem with the progress bar that shows the refresh - it doesn't move when the sliding menu slides out!

https://github.com/chrisbanes/ActionBar-PullToRefresh/tree/development

https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu

Comment: use android action bar drawer. It is better than sliding menu library. IT crashes sometimes if you use fragment

Comment: Secondly, post your code too. and use gmail pull to refresh library. Google it.

Comment: The navigation drawer is no good for my project because it doesn't slide the actionbar out at the same time

Comment: at what same time? sliding menu crashes sometimes.i have used sliding drawer for left and right menu and crouton for top to bottom slide notification menu plus pull to refresh. rest is your wish

Comment: What i have done is when the nav drawer is opened, if you scroll within it, then pull to refres will not work and when you close the drawer then pull to refresh will work, and if you select an item in the nav drawer, then the nav drawer closes and the custom smooth progress bar is se visible till the service executes.

Comment: thanks for your comments, I haven't had any crashes caused by the library yet on any of my devices. So I've just had to set the progressbar to not be in the loading state when the action bar is not completely visible and then turn it back on when the action bar slides back into view